# the disk iops from scylla_setup iotune study my disk is different from fio test data

Tags: scylla

when use scylla_setup, iotune study my reuslt is:

```
Measuring sequential write bandwidth: 473 MB/s
Measuring sequential read bandwidth: 499 MB/s
Measuring random write IOPS: 1902 IOPS
Measuring random read IOPS: 1999 IOPS
```

iops is 1900-2000,
when use fio,

```
fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test --filename=/dev/sdc1 --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=4G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75
```

the result is

```
test: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=11697: Wed Jun 26 08:58:13 2019
   read: IOPS=47.6k, BW=186MiB/s (195MB/s)(3070MiB/16521msec)
   bw (  KiB/s): min=187240, max=192136, per=100.00%, avg=190278.42, stdev=985.15, samples=33
   iops        : min=46810, max=48034, avg=47569.61, stdev=246.38, samples=33
  write: IOPS=15.9k, BW=62.1MiB/s (65.1MB/s)(1026MiB/16521msec)
   bw (  KiB/s): min=62656, max=65072, per=100.00%, avg=63591.52, stdev=590.96, samples=33
   iops        : min=15664, max=16268, avg=15897.88, stdev=147.74, samples=33
  cpu          : usr=4.82%, sys=12.81%, ctx=164053, majf=0, minf=23
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=100.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.1%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwt: total=785920,262656,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=64

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=186MiB/s (195MB/s), 186MiB/s-186MiB/s (195MB/s-195MB/s), io=3070MiB (3219MB), run=16521-16521msec
  WRITE: bw=62.1MiB/s (65.1MB/s), 62.1MiB/s-62.1MiB/s (65.1MB/s-65.1MB/s), io=1026MiB (1076MB), run=16521-16521msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  sdc: ios=780115/260679, merge=0/0, ticks=792798/230409, in_queue=1023170, util=99.47%
```

read iops is 46000 - 48000,write iops is 15000-16000

Answer (score 0):

(NB: It looks like the questioner filed this as a Scylla Github issue too - https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/4604 )

> [Why is] the disk iops from scylla_setup iotune [...] different from fio test data

Different benchmarks, different results:

- Scylla may have been using a much bigger block size (e.g. 64k) per I/O (this is likely the biggest factor). As you make the block size bigger (up to some maximum due to diminishing returns) the bandwidth (i.e. total amount of data you can send in say a second) achieved with that block size goes up but the IOPS you get will typically down (you are sending more data per I/O after all). This is normal!
- Scylla could be using buffered I/O (rather than direct I/O)
- Scylla may have been benchmarking reads and writes separately
- Scylla may have been using a bigger queue depth
- Scylla may have been batching its submissions differently
- Scylla may be writing a different type of data
- And so on...

In general, it's very difficult to take benchmarks done with different tools and compare them directly to each other - you would need to know what they are doing under the hood for any comparison to be meaningful. Trying to look at IOPS or bandwidth in isolation without more context is meaningless as you typically trade one off against the other. It's better to use the same benchmark tool with identical options to compare two different machines changes or to measure the impact of tuning on the same machine.

TLDR; This is likely an apples to oranges comparison where the tools are measuring different contexts.

PS: `gtod_reduce` is a go faster stripe that very few people actually need. If your hardware isn't capable of doing gigabytes per second and you're not seeing your CPU maxed out it's unlikely reducing `gettimeofday` calls is going to nudge the result very much.

(This question might be more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (and thus get better replies there) because it's not directly about programming)

Comment: when i use block_size 256k，read result is  is  closed to scylla_setup, but the disk xfs block_size is 4096,shall i change the file system settings?

Comment: You don't say how you XFS told you the block size but it is likely reporting the MINIMUM block size (which is different to the OPTIMAL block size). What is sent down to that disk must be a multiple of the minimum block size (and filesystems will do tricks to make sure that happens) but a program can send the filesystem more. I doubt changing the filesystem settings (if you mean what's passed to `mkfs`) is the right thing to do. From what little I know of your scenario it sounds like everything is working normally - you were comparing two programs benchmarking different things...